# Laravel 5.3 Passport (401: Unauthorized) OAuth personal token

Tags: php, laravel, api

Send request:

```
authorization: Bearer token
accept: application/json
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36
```

And get response:

```
{"error":"Unauthenticated."}
```

Why?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во первых здесь SO на русском. А во вторых раз возвращает ошибку значит смотрите у себя в коде где и на каком этапе ошибка. Телепатов нет, и ваш код не знаем. Раз пишет что Unauthenticated значит токен невалидный.

Comment: Устанавливал по мануалу с офф сайта: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport

Велосипедов не изобретал :)